# Get the value of a name referring to a formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, we could define a name that refers to a cell. We could also define a name that refers to a formula. I would like to know if it is possible to get the information (especially the evaluated value) of such a name in VBA.

For example, in the following worksheet, I defined a name `toACell` that refers to Cell C5. By `MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Names("toACell").RefersToRange.Value` in VBA, its value `10` is well printed.

[image]

I also defined a name `notToACell` that refers to `Sheet1!$C$5+100`. We see that the name manager shows well its result value `110`. But `MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Names("notToACell").RefersToRange.Value` in VBA returns an error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get its evaluated result (ie, `110`) in VBA?

PS: I know [Application.Evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) can evaluate the formula. But there is a possibility that Name Manager already evaluates the names, and I want to access the result directly.

Comment: There is not a possibility that you can access the displayed evaluated value in the Name Manger. You're welcome to look through the [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name) properties if you think otherwise.

Comment: Well, how are you so sure? At least we see that the evaluated values are displayed in the name manager.

Comment: Because I've looked through and tested said properties.